# Update function broken in C++ Azure Mobile Library

Tags: c++, windows-8, windows-runtime, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to update a record in one of my Azure Mobile tables using the “update” function in the [azure mobile](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/11/05/using-windows-azure-mobile-services-from-c-windows-store-apps.aspx) C++ header.  But I get an exception.  Below is what my code looks like:

```
void DBUtils::DBQuestion::UpdateQuestionInTable(std::shared_ptr<azure::mobile::table> table)
{
       auto obj = json::value::object();
       obj[U("id")] = json::value::string(ID);
       obj[U("QuestionText")] = json::value::string(QuestionText);
       obj[U("AnswerLatitude")] = json::value::number(AnswerLatitude);
       obj[U("AnswerLongitude")] = json::value::number(AnswerLongitude);

       table->update(obj);
}
```

I have verified that the ID above is a valid one actually present in the table.  A similar insert operation (which doesn’t specify the ID field) actually succeeds:

```
void DBUtils::DBQuestion::InsertIntoTable(std::shared_ptr<azure::mobile::table> table)
{
       auto obj = json::value::object();
       obj[U("QuestionText")] = json::value::string(QuestionText);
       obj[U("AnswerLatitude")] = json::value::number(AnswerLatitude);
       obj[U("AnswerLongitude")] = json::value::number(AnswerLongitude);

       table->insert(obj);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suppose the name of the exception you get is a state secret?

Comment: `I have verified that the ID above is a valid one actually present in the table` _Prove it_. Present a [testcase](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Mobile recently updated its table schema so that the Id field is now a string, which gets filled in by the server with a Guid value if the client doesn’t set it.

This change has introduced a bug in the C++ library.  As a workaround, you can try calling the other overload for update, the one that takes the ID string and the object.

```
void DBUtils::DBQuestion::UpdateQuestionInTable(utility::string_t id, std::shared_ptr<azure::mobile::table> table)
{
    auto obj = json::value::object();
    obj[U("QuestionText")] = json::value::string(QuestionText);
    obj[U("AnswerLatitude")] = json::value::number(AnswerLatitude);
    obj[U("AnswerLongitude")] = json::value::number(AnswerLongitude);

    ID = id;

    table->update(ID, obj);
}
```